# How to highlight Excel cells with a list of options?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a sheet with Locations. E.g.;

```
 'Las Vega - Nevada',
 'Englewood - Colorado',
 'Hot Springs - Arkansas', 
'Airdrie - Alberta',
 'Houston - Texas', etc.
```

I am trying to highlight cells that have the states of USA.

In Conditional Formatting, I can Highlight cells where 'Text That Contains' the list of the states. But some states have 'New York' North Carolina, North Dakota, New Hampshire, etc.

Should I include quotes to select the whole word?

Answer (score 1):

Base your CFR on the following formula.

```
=MATCH(REPLACE(A1, 1, FIND(" - ", A1)+2, TEXT(,)), Z:Z, 0)
```

... where the list of states is in column Z.

[image]

Comment: Thank you kindly. But I think it would be neater if I put the list of States in another worksheet 'States' in the same workbook. What would be the formula then please?

Comment: Something like `=MATCH(REPLACE(A1, 1, FIND(" - ", A1)+2, TEXT(,)), 'States'!$A:$A, 0)` where the states list is in column A of the States worksheet.